# Obtain square image with Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I need to obtain the square version of my images using instagram API. I could obtain the original images in the original ratio (vertical or horizontal) but not the square version in an acceptable size. [Here](https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/12534671_1553893048260710_1635778442_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTE3MDQyODkwNTY0MDc4MzYwNQ%3D%3D.2) is the image I could get with the API, which is horizontal. I would want to get [this square](https://scontent-mad1-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/c140.0.360.360/12534671_1553893048260710_1635778442_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTE3MDQyODkwNTY0MDc4MzYwNQ%3D%3D.2.c) version that appears in my instagram profile. 
I could also get the [square image in a small size](https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15//c140.0.360.360/12534671_1553893048260710_1635778442_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTE3MDQyODkwNTY0MDc4MzYwNQ%3D%3D.2.c), but not the larger one.

Comment: What does your request to the api look like? If you're getting back the instagram JSON object from their end point, you should be able to look through the different images by logging your response to the console. $.ajax({
  url:  'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxxx/media/recent/?client_id=xxxxx',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  count: 20, //max for sandbox
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    }
});

Comment: I'm obtaining an XML response that contain 3 different image sizes. One is a small square and the rest are not square.